# why ajax duplicate content

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hello I am new here and working on a project that requires this option of "Viewing content in DIV `.posts_area`, from database using AJAX",
I had a problem that the content I get in `.posts_area` sometimes duplicate itself.

Can anyone help me with the solution and I would also be happy for more detailed explanation about the subject.

```
// AJAX in
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag = 0;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getData.php',
    data: {
      'offset': 0,
      'limit': 6
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
      $('.posts_area').append(data);
      flag += 3;
    }
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getData.php',
        data: {
          'offset': flag,
          'limit': 5
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.posts_area').append(data);
          flag += 3;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

```
//getData.php

<?php
include ('config/config.php');
include 'includes/classes/user.php';
include 'includes/classes/post.php';






if(isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])){
    
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    $offset = $_GET['offset'];
    

     
    $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted='no'  ORDER by id DESC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset} ");
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($data ) > 0) {
        

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data) ){
        

                        
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        
                        $comments_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id'");
                        $comments_check_num = mysqli_num_rows($comments_check);
                        
                        
                        ?>
                            <script>
                            function myFunction<?php echo $id; ?>()  {
                              var x = document.getElementById("toggleComment<?php echo $id; ?>");
                              if (x.style.display === "block") {
                                x.style.display = "none";
                              } else {
                                x.style.display = "block";
                              }
                            }
                            </script>
                        <?php
        
                        $added_by_user = $row['added_by_user'];
                        
                        $post_profile_pic = $row['post_profile_pic'];
                        
                        $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                        
                        $body = $row['body'];
                        
                        $date_time = $row['date_added'];
                        
                        $user_session = $_SESSION['user'];   

                        if($user_session == $added_by_user)
                        $delete_button = "<form action = 'delete_post.php?id=$id' method='POST' id = 'delete_post_id_form'>
                                
                                <input type ='submit'  class = 'delete_post_class_input' id = 'delete_post_id_input' value = 'Delete'></input>
                                
                                </form>";
                        else 
                        $delete_button = "";
                        
                    //  if($user_session == $added_by_user)
                    //  $update_button = "<form action = 'update_post.php?post_id=$id' method='POST'>
                                
                    //          <input type ='submit'  class = 'update_post_class' id = 'update_post_id' value = 'Update'></input>
                                
                    //          </form>";
                    //  else 
                    //  $update_button = "";
                    


                        $str .= "<div class='status_post' >
                                <div class='on_post_profile_pic_class' id = 'on_post_profile_pic_id'>
                                    <a href='$added_by_user' class='posted_by_on_img'><img src='$post_profile_pic' width='50' id = 'on_post_profile_img_id'></img></a> 
                                </div>

                                <div class='posted_by1' id='added_by_on_post' style='color:#ACACAC;'>
                                    <a href='$added_by_user' class='posted_by'> $added_by </a> 
                                </div>

                                            <img src='assets/images/icons/more_info_button_black_down.png' onClick='show_hide()'alt='more_info_on_post_button_black_down_button_alt' class='more_info_on_post_button_black_down_btn' id ='more_info_on_post_button_black_down_btn_id' name ='more_info_name'></img>
                                            <img src='assets/images/icons/more_info_button_black_up.png' alt='more_info_on_post_button_black_up_button_alt' class='more_info_on_post_button_black_up_btn' id ='more_info_on_post_button_black_up_btn_id'></img>
                                        
                                <div class = 'date_added_on_post_class' id = 'date_added_on_post_id'>$date_time</div>
                                <div class = 'update_post_class' id = 'update_post_id'>$update_button</div> 
                                <div class = 'delete_post_class_div' id = 'delete_post_id'>$delete_button</div> 
<div id='post_body' dir=auto>
$body
</div>

                                    
                                </div>

                            </div>
                                                                <div class='span_class' id='span_id' onclick='myFunction$id()' >Comments($comments_check_num)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                                    <hr>
                            <div class='post_comment' id='toggleComment$id' >
                            
                                <iframe src='comment_frame.php?post_id=$id' class = 'comment_iframe_class' id='comment_iframe' frameborder='0'></iframe>
                                

                            </div>
                            <hr class ='hr'>";
        
    }
    
echo $str;

}
    
}

?>
```

Comment: Probably the first function is not finished yet, while the second already runs. You'll then get the duplicate content. Try adding a boolean like `var isBusy`

Comment: Look up "debouncing" to keep from running an event handler too frequently.

Comment: Use .html() instead of append

Comment: do i need to set here a counter of alredy posted posts  id? if yes so how do il set this counter?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.posts_area').html(data);
```

Use this instead of append()

Comment: It does not show the posts by ID and every time I scroll down it reloads the top in random posts.